# ReferenceError: _jsxDEV is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, turbopack

I am working on webapp with Next.js 14 (pages route), Tailwind CSS and Next.js turbopack. The below error comes unexpectedly at any time during hot reload(even if there are no syntax or runtime errors), goes away only after refreshing the page and cannot be reproduced(by me).

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: _jsxDEV is not defined

Call Stack
ProductFoundCard
file:///home/bibekoli/Project/user/.next/static/chunks/%5Bnext%5D_entry_page-loader_ts_dcc0c2._.js (1462:12)
renderWithHooks
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (16306:6)
updateFunctionComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (19588:12)
beginWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21601:6)
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4164:8)
Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4214:10)
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4277:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27452:6)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26557:4)
workLoopSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26466:2)
renderRootSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26434:6)
performSyncWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26086:19)
flushSyncCallbacks
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12042:17)
flushSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26201:4)
Object.scheduleRefresh
file:///home/bibekoli/Project/user/.next/static/chunks/node_modules_react-dom_cjs_react-dom_development_ab7e07.js (23368:17)
<unknown>
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js (265:15)
Set.forEach
<anonymous>
Object.performReactRefresh
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js (254:20)
applyUpdate
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/dist/internal/helpers.js (122:20)
<unknown>
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/dist/internal/helpers.js (131:8)
```